# What are the applications of Sigma Function?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, divisor-sum

I read about the Sigma Function today.It tells that-

> The $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of all the positive divisors of $n$.

But I had no idea how they can be useful.What are the practical applications or uses of the sigma function? Are there some seemingly big mathematical problems that can be solved in seconds by applying the Sigma Function?

Thanks for any reply!!

Comment: check out https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function they give some good examples

Comment: The Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to a inequality relating to the divisor function.

Comment: @shaihorowitz They give examples on how to calculate the sigma values....but I am looking for applications of the sigma function....

Comment: @tatan I feel the word "applications" is a bit vague...

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RobinsTheorem.html

Comment: You tell me how the Mona Lisa is useful, and I'll tell you how $\sigma$ is useful.

Comment: I would assume a large part of interest in $\sigma(n)$ is basically ancestral. A number is called *perfect* if $\sigma(n) = n$, and the case of even perfect numbers was settled some 2300 years ago.

Comment: @Gerrymyerson Mona Lisa is beautiful, no use. Are you saying Riemann hypothesis is beautiful but of no use?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Do you want to say all beautiful things are useful in the sense of their beauty only?:-)

Comment: What I'm saying is that usefulness is not the be-all and end-all of why we do things.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the main properties of the sigma function are that

1. its Dirichlet series $\zeta (s) \zeta(s-1) = \sum \sigma(n)n^{-s}$ is related to the Riemann zeta function
2. the sum of the $\sigma$ function on intervals is the famous problem of lattice point counting in a hyperbola

I don't think there are direct applications, but 1-2 provide a relation between some difficult counting problems in analytic number theory and the easier problem of sums over lattice points.

Answer (score 0):

a general relationship between how n's prime factorization effects (n+1) prime factorization would offer a proof to the reiman hypothesis, collatz conjecture,  and more conjectures then I can count.

Comment: I don't think I see how this is related to the "sum of divisors" function. Could you elaborate?

Comment: consider sigma (p)  p prime well then it's divisors are 1 and P so we have 1+p as divisors now consider sigma (p+1) what do we know?  that's at the heart of this function

Answer (score 0):

The sigma function also shows up naturally in the study of modular forms and elliptic curves, which makes it significant in algebraic geometry (hence physics) and in cryptography.